# ionic v1 application multiple tabs scrolling issue

Tags: css, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

tabs are working fine .multiple tabs in menu .

[image]

but after scrolling tabs showing like this

[image]

> scroll menus as per tab item

i want to show active tab menu in center even after scrolling tab item .tab menu hiding need to scroll manually to set which tab is active

```
<ion-nav-view name="tab-dash" style="background-color: #f3f3f3;" > 
  <div class="item item-text-wrap ng-enter-stagger" >
    <div class="backBllue"> 
       <label class="item item-input" > <input type="text" placeholder="Search 
        Jobs" ng-model="search" >
        <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon" ></i>
      </label>
     </div>
   </div> 
</ion-nav-view>
```

Comment: '<ion-nav-view name="tab-dash" style="background-color: #f3f3f3;" >
           <div class="item  item-text-wrap ng-enter-stagger" >
                   <div class="backBllue">
                    
                      <label class="item item-input" >
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search Jobs" ng-model="search" > <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon" ></i> </label>
                    
                    </div>  
                      
                  
                    </div>
                </ion-nav-view>'

Comment: ionic v1 simple tabs